# Perl WWW:Mechanize::Firefox disable alert

Tags: perl, firefox, mechanize

I am using Perl's `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` to automate some website interaction. I am stuck at dealing with the alert popup. Until I click it I cannot go to the next stage. I am looking for a way to either disable it or Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

I have tried the following till now without any success:

- `$mech->eval("alert = function(val){console.log(val+' (alert disabled)');};");`
- `$mech->eval("window.alert = function(val){console.log(val+' (alert disabled)');};");`
- `$mech->eval_in_page("alert = function(val){console.log(val+' (alert disabled)');};");`
- `$mech->eval_in_page('alert("Hello");', { alert => sub { print "Captured alert: '@_'\n" } });`
- `$mech->eval_in_page('', { alert => sub { print "Captured alert: '@_'\n" } });`

My test files are at:

- https://github.com/jahagirdar/voter-reg/blob/master/bin/a.html
- https://github.com/jahagirdar/voter-reg/blob/master/bin/fill_form.pl

I am using Firefox version 15.0.1 "Mozilla Firefox Ubuntu canonical version 1".

Installed addons are mozrepl 1.1 and Mozilla Ubuntu modifications 2.1.1.